# How to search JSON object and extract the key/value pair?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to search a JSON Object and extract the Key/Value **pairs** for `'name'` and `'id'` below. I would like to extract all instances of the `'name'` and `'id'`:

```
{
"response": [
    {
        "additionalInfo": [],
        "id": "b6549916-b8e1-4131-b0be-f4a3daee26fc",
        "instanceTenantId": "5ffc97db91d68700c7ea827a",
        "name": "Global",
        "siteHierarchy": "b6549916-a8e1-4131-b0be-f4a3daee26fc",
        "siteNameHierarchy": "Global"
    },
    {
        "additionalInfo": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "addressInheritedFrom": "66284774-4ae4-42a1-b27c-68231c98d7db",
                    "type": "area"
                },
                "nameSpace": "Location"
            }
        ],
        "id": "4ffb292c-4cc8-444b-8978-61b97c6874db",
        "instanceTenantId": "5ffc97db91d68700c7ea827a",
        "name": "Peak Tester",
        "parentId": "66a84774-4ae4-42a1-b27c-68231c98d7db",
        "siteHierarchy": "b6549916-b8e1-4131-b0be-f4a3daee21fc/66a84774-4ae4-42a1-b27c-68231c98d7db/4ffb292c-4cc8-444b-8978-61b97c6874db",
        "siteNameHierarchy": "Global/Template Site/Peak Tester"
    }
]
```

}

I have tried several things that are not working.

```
for elements in site_info['response']:
for item in elements:
    if item == 'name':
        print(item)
```

This only prints the output of `'name'` and not the value. I would like the value as well as the key.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In Python, there is no such thing as "a JSON Object". Once you have parsed the JSON in any normal way, what you have is *an ordinary dict* which works *the same way* as *any other dict* that you create *in any other way*.

Comment: "I'm a python beginner so I appreciate any help" If you do not know fundamentals, like the things you can do with the built-in types, then you should follow a tutorial first before trying to solve your own problems.

Comment: Thanks Karl, I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply when you have the `key` and you need the `value`, you have to do this:

```
>>> dictionary['key']
'value'
```

In your case:

```
if item == 'name':
    print(item['name'])
```

Anyway you can simply omitt the `if` statement this way:

```
for item in elements:
    print(item['name'])
```

Comment: @southcarolinaswampfox, happy to have helped you. Anyway welcome to StackOverflow! If an answer worked for you, you can accept it to mark it as a working answer.

Comment: You don't have to iterate over the `dict`; you know the two keys you want, and can check for the directly with `if 'name' in elements: print(elements['name'])`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have your answer, which is great.

```
data = { "response": [ {"name" : "fred"}, {"name" : "tom"}]} # data is a dictionary

arr = data['response'] # arr is a list of dictionaries

for i in arr:
    print('name', i['name']) # lookup the name value from each sub-dictionary
```